# BigQuery Table Data Export

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to export data from `BigQuery` Table using python api. Table contains 1 to 4 million of rows. So I have kept `maxResults` parameter to maximum i.e. 100000 and then paging through. But problem is that in One page I am getting 2652 rows only so number of paging is too much. Can anyone provide reason for this or solution to deal. Format is JSON. 
Or can I export data into CSV format without using GCS?

I tried by inserting job and keeping `allowLargeResults =true`, but the result remain same.

Below is my query body :

```
queryData = {'query':query,
                     'maxResults':100000,
                     'timeoutMs':'130000'}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to export data from table without using GCS by using bq command line tool https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/bq-command-line-tool like this:

```
bq --format=prettyjson query --n=10000000 "SELECT * from publicdata:samples.shakespeare"
```

You can use `--format=json` depending on your needs as well.

Comment: Actually I can't use bq_line, thats why I wrote my own code to import data.

Comment: Could you explain why you can't use bq cli?
Maybe there is a way to overcome your limitations.

Comment: it's just not in requirement. I have different working environment.

Comment: can I know where the result set will be placed in unix path folder?. Will it be with in bq folder?

Answer (score 1):

Actual page size is determined not by row count, but rather by size of those rows in given page. I think it is something around 10MB
User can alsoset  maxResults to limit rows in page in addition to above criteria

Comment: yes, this is true size limit is 10MB but when I am writing to csv file on my local size of file is around 4 MB.

Comment: my guess is that size is calculated based on verbous json format